# How to tile a drawable file in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-widget

Like the title. I have a small drawable file, but the ImageView is much larger than it. How I can fill it without left any extra space?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to "fill" the ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

If you are trying to "tile" look into [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) and `setTileModeXY()`

Comment: How about fill ImageView with the multi-same drawable files not change it's size

Comment: Did you try BitmapDrawable, setTileMode? I have not done this personally but the description of a BitmapDrawable is "A Drawable that wraps a bitmap and can be tiled, stretched, or aligned."

Comment: I just put the drawable in the background, It works for me. Thanks.

Comment: So how did you get this to work exactly? You created a BitmapDrawable from the image and then simply set it as the background of the ImageView and it was tilled?

Answer (score 5):

Create a drawable in res folder, name it `tile_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/zig_zag"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Use  this drawable as the Background for your ImageView, Done!

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_drawable" />
```

That's the way to do it via XML

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code snippet:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable  = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile_image));
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

this sample fills imageView with tile_image and repeate it in X-Direction. You can use other method to tile in Y-Direction or both:

```
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT,TileMode.REPEAT);
```